# Ajax webmethod in asp.net problems

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

This is my jquery function. I have two functions. `showgrid()` function load data to html table. From that if i `editrow()` funcion. i'm getting error.

```
function showgrid() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "CourseSearch.aspx/DisplayCourses",
        data: "{'strSearchText':'" + $("#txtSearchText").val() + "'}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
            //$("#searchCoursesDiv").append("<tr><td style='color:#000888;'>" + data.d[i].CourseName + "</td><td>|</td><td style='color:#000888;'>" + data.d[i].CourseCode + "</td></tr><tr><td border='0px' colspan='3'><hr/></td></tr>");
                $("#searchCoursesDiv").append("<table><tr><td align='left' width='500px' style='color:#000888;' colspan='3'>" + data.d[i].CourseName + " | " + data.d[i].CourseCode + "</td></tr><tr><td colspan='3' valign='bottom'><hr /></td></tr><tr><td align='left'>Description:</td><td></td><td rowspan='2' align='right'><a href='#'>Course Details...</a><br/><a href=# onclick='EditRow( " + data.d[i].CourseCode + ")'>Nominate as Trainer...</a></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td></tr><table>");
            }
        },
        error: function (result) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
    });
    // });
    return false;
}

//This function returns coursecode when user click html table row,.. this function get value from showgrid function and return value to page.but this funcion is not firing.i m getting error when click editrow() funciont in showgrid funcion.

function EditRow(CourseCode) {
    alert(CourseCode);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "CourseSearch.aspx/StoreCourseCode",
        data: "{'CourseCode':'" + CourseCode + "'}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            //                    $("#displayasstname").html(data.d);
            window.location = "nextpage.aspx";
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });                     
}
```

This is my HTML design code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="searchCoursesDiv">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Issues: When i click `editrow()` function, I'm getting an error like this `coursecode 'DOTNET3.0' undefined.`

Answer (score 1):

remove your json string in the post... like this

```
data: {"CourseCode": CourseCode },
```

instead

```
data: "{'CourseCode':'" + CourseCode + "'}",
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `JSON.stringify` to manage your parameters :

```
var data = JSON.stringify({ CourseCode: CourseCode, ... });
```

then :

```
function EditRow(CourseCode) {

        var data = JSON.stringify({ CourseCode: CourseCode, ... });
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "CourseSearch.aspx/StoreCourseCode",
                data: data,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    //                    $("#displayasstname").html(data.d);
                    window.location = "nextpage.aspx";

                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
                        });                     
        }
```